# Silverlight 4 Multicast streaming

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Has anyone had an opportunity to do multicast streaming in Silverlight 4?  I'm desparately seeking any information on the subject - links, docs - anything.  Code samples would rock!  I realize that it has only been released as a developer edition, but I signed on to do a demo before the year is through...(not too smart, I know)

Answer (score 0):

I've done UDP multicast in Silverlight 4 beta.  Currently, there isn't much out there, which makes it difficult. I've been meaning to put some stuff about it up on the web.  But here's my results (these results are for UDP multicast single source):

- Multicast only works on internal LAN.
- A silverlight client not on the LAN, where the multicast host is, can NOT recieve packets sent by the host.
- A silverlight client not on the LAN, where the mulitcast host is, CAN send unicast UDP packets to the host.

I really hate these results.  I was hoping to do a game using UDP sockets.  However, two-way unicast communication is not supported in Silverlight 4 beta, I don't understand why!?  If anybody else has any results please let me know.

Oh, and also you have to host a UDP policy server on port 9430, before you can successfully send/receive packets.

Answer (score 0):

Multicast protocols aren't supported in Internet routers. (you can't create a Multicast group on an internet router). So it isn't a Silverlight problem.